# read a file and Try to complete the missing information in the database

Tags: python

So far I have this to split completed and uncompleted but im not sure how to try to recover the missing data this is an example of a full row :

```
Ahmad Omar;802424333;10 April 2000;0550123456;A10B20;Audi;2018;15 April 2020;17 April 2020;350
```

We are supposed to recover names ids dob car name and model year if it was possible
and is it possible to change this code so that instead of reading a file it reads all the files in a folder

```py
  def splitCompleteAndIncomplete():
      f = open("temp.txt","r")
      completeFile = open("CarRentalCompleted.txt","w")
      incompleteFile = open("CarRentalMissing.txt","w")
      for row in f.readlines():
        li = row.split(";")
        incompleteFlag=0
        for i in li:
          if len(i) == 0:
            incompleteFlag=1
        if(incompleteFlag == 1):
          incompleteFile.write(row)
        else:
          completeFile.write(row)
      f.close()
    splitCompleteAndIncomplete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the os module and read the documentation for os.path.listdir() and os.path.join() methods.
You can prompt to input a folder destination and listdir method will list all files in the directory and join method will complete the file location. This will surely work, if there's any problem do reply

Answer (score 0):

You can simple **destructure** your values in a single row and use them like this:

```py
row = 'Ahmad Omar;802424333;10 April 2000;0550123456;A10B20;Audi;2018;15 April 2020;17 April 2020;350'

name, uid, dob, cid, cname, modelyear, *rest = row.split(";")
print((name, uid, dob, cname, modelyear))
```

Output:

```py
('Ahmad Omar', '802424333', '10 April 2000', 'A10B20', 'Audi')
```

To read all files from `foldername = "./myfolder"`:

```py
filenames = os.listdir(foldername)
for name in filenames:
    # read csv
    rows = ...

    for row in rows:
        name, uid, dob, cid, cname, modelyear, *rest = row.split(";")
        print((name, uid, dob, cname, modelyear))
```